# Is there a way to show a list of minimized windows in Unity?

Tags: unity

I know how the Unity dock works and I like it. But I need a fast tool to list all the opened windows instead of looking at the dock and find out which of those have a backlight arrow sign... Is it possible?

Comment: minimized windows are not the same as "all windows other than the one I'm looking at".

Answer (score 3):

Super+w doesn't show minimized windows, but Alt+Tab does.

Comment: As of 16.04 Super + W also shows minimized windows. Tested it just now

Answer (score 0):

You can super-w, it opens an expose-like view of all opened windows.